# How to make tikz center the cells of a matrix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I want to construct complicated things in tikz matrices (but don't we all), and when I'm done, I want the rows and columns of the matrix to align along the centers of these complicated things.  Here is an example of what goes wrong:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix
 {
  \path node{a} node[right] {b}; \\
  \node{c};\\
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You will see that the second row is aligned at the *left* of the first row.  The reason for this is explained quite clearly in the tikz manual: rows and columns are aligned along the "origins" of the cells.

What this means is that each cell is considered a tiny picture with an origin (that is, (0,0)) and all those points are put on a grid.  It's clear from this that what has happened in the above picture is that the `\path` begins at (0,0) and moves right, and likewise the `\node` begins at its (0,0) and moves right, and (as claimed) those two origins are put in a line.

Unfortunately, that's not what I want and there's no obvious way to change it.  I want to tell tikz that the "origin" of the top cell is the center of its bounding box.  If it were a single node that would be easy: just write `[anchor = center]` as an option.

But I can't put paths in nodes, so there's no way to do that directly.  And although it is possible to pass an `[xshift = <dimen>]` to the `\path`, I would have to know what that shift is before starting, whereas (since it is *such* a complicated figure) I can't know that until the end, when it is too late to perform a coordinate transformation.

How can I do this?  Basically, I want to give an entirely relative construction and then slap a coordinate system on it afterwards.  Alternatively, I want to know if there is any matrix option that does this that I have overlooked.  Another alternative: is there a different way to achieve this alignment without using matrices?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't put paths in nodes, but you can put paths in tikzpictures in nodes!  Compare the first and second lines.  I added some styling as in Section 17.3 of the PGF (2.10) manual.[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw=black},font=\Huge]
 \matrix[draw=red]
 {
  \node{a} node[right] {b}; \fill[blue] (0,0) circle (2pt); \\
  \node{\tikz{\node{a} node[right] {b};}}; \fill[blue] (0,0) circle (2pt); \\
 \node{c}; \fill[blue] (0,0) circle (2pt);\\
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note how the options in the outer `tikzpicture` environment descend into the `\tikz` group inside the node.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know options descended like that.  That makes this trick virtually painless.  But why are the boxes in the nested tikz larger than the ones outside?

Comment: @Ryan: that is a good question.  I can only guess that by using `inner sep` and `outer sep` in the right scopes you can get the boxes in the second line to be the same size as those in the first line.

Comment: Hmm, but that is the sort of ugliness I want to avoid.  I mean, what is a good `inner sep`?  Tests show that setting `inner sep = 0.3333em` (the default) changes neither the bounding box of the first row nodes nor of the nested nodes in the second row.  That is, somehow, tikz thinks that both the small *and* the large boxes have the same inner sep!  I believe this is a legitimate bug.

Comment: It turns out that for my application, I am setting `inner sep = 0` globally anyway, so this (bug or not) is not a problem with your solution for me.  I will wait a little while before accepting it in case someone else comes up with something surprising.