# How to align a TikZ matrix' cells w.r.t. their centers?

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment, tikz-matrix

The following question may be a duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5838/21685). The problem I will describe below is very similar to the one described in the possible duplicate. However, the duplicate seems to be concerned with nodes, and by the poster's own admission a solution to his problem could be simply to "write `[anchor = center]` as an option", whereas in my case nodes are not involved, and passing the `anchor=center` option to the matrix has no effect.

---

The following LaTeX code was saved in the file `~/test.tex`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\grid}[1]{\draw (0,0) rectangle ++(#1,#1);}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[row sep=0pt]
{
    \grid{1} & \grid{2} \\
    \grid{3} & \grid{4} \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code creates four squares of several sizes, and arranges them in a 2x2 matrix.

Then the following commands were executed in the Terminal.

```
> cd ~
> lualatex test
```

Consequently the file `~/test.pdf` was created. When opened in a PDF viewer the file displayed as follows.

[image]

As can be seen, the squares are left-aligned in each column and bottom-aligned in each row.

1. How can I align them vertically (resp. horizontally) w.r.t. their centers?
2. How can I align them simultaneously vertically and horizontally w.r.t. to their centers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\grid}[1]{\draw (0,0) rectangle ++(#1,#1);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
N/.style = {draw, minimum size=#1 cm, anchor=center,
            node contents={}}
                    ]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,
        column sep=1mm, 
        row sep=1mm]
{
\node[N=1]; & \node[N=2];  \\
\node[N=3]; & \node[N=4];  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
From OP comment follows, that question is not entirely clear and that answer should provide general solution. What this mean is not explained, so I guess, that contents are some text which can be in  in several lines. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix[matrix of nodes,
        nodes={fill=gray!10, % remove in real document
               align=center, anchor=center, font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
        column sep=1mm, 
        row sep=1mm]
{
\node{a};       & \node{a\\b};  \\
\node{a, b\\c}; & \node{a\\b\\cdefgh};  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
It seems that you actually looking for a table in which you can insert images, To my opinion the `tabularray` package can be handy. A dummy example:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
    node distance = 2mm,
       dot/.style = {circle, fill=gray!30},
    baseline=(current bounding box.center) % <---
       }
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[c] Q[c]}}
\tikz{\node (a) [dot,label=a] {};
      \node (b) [dot,label=b, right=of a] {};
       }
        & \tikz{\node (a) [dot,label=a] {};
                \node (b) [dot, right=of a] {};
                \node (c) [dot,label=c, above=of b] {};
                }    \\
\tikz{\node (a) [dot] {a};
      \node (b) [dot, right=of a] {b};
       }
        & \tikz{\node (a) [dot] {a};
                \node (b) [dot, right=of a] {b};
                \node (c) [dot, right=of b] {c};
                \node (d) [dot, above=of b] {d};
                \node (e) [dot, below=of b] {e};
                }    \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, however the minimal working example I listed in my original post is a simplified version of the situation I face in real life. In the real life situation the pictures inside the matrix' cells are more complex than mere squares. Therefore, I seek a general solution.

Comment: @EvanAad, that is general solution. replace nodes with actual matrix node continents and accordingly change `nodes` style. Please provide an example with some dummy matrix contents, that question will be more clear.

Comment: +1 Zarko beat me to the solution

Comment: @jsbibra, thank you. Ah, today I was asked for early morning (late night) working shift in which I have some time to look on site ...

Comment: Zarko, I don't have any text in my matrix cells. Only non-trivial drawings. Your solution doesn't seem to apply to my case at all. I seek a general solution. Your solution is specialized to text nodes.

Comment: @EvanAad, insert drawings, if this is some `tikzpicture` can be fragile.  Inserting them in some `tikz` nodes or matrix cell should be avoided. It may be better to use table instead of `matrix`

Comment: Maybe that's it. Maybe I simply need to use a regular,  non-TikZ table. Thanks!

Comment: @EvanAad, see addendum. It is simple. In it you can replace `\tikz{...}` with `\begin{tikzpicture}[local options] ... \end{tikzpicture}`